# Is there a faster way to compute $\left\lfloor{(k + 1)m \over n}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor {km\over n}\right\rfloor$?

Tags: arithmetic, fractions, integers, ceiling-and-floor-functions, computational-mathematics

I'm looking to compute the integer difference between the $k$th and $(k+1)$th multiples of a fraction, i.e.

$$\left\lfloor{(k + 1)m \over n}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor {km\over n}\right\rfloor$$

where all variables are positive integers (and they're not predetermined constants).

I'm already speeding this up by doing $km + m$ instead of $(k + 1)m$ so that I can factor out $km$, but unfortunately, this computation requires two integer divisions, and integer division is quite slow.

Is there a faster way to compute the same exact value?
I feel like the simplicity of the problem might admit a simple solution, but for some reason I'm not seeing one.

Comment: I don't think this question can have a consistent solution; you'll end up with an answer in terms of $\lfloor \  \rfloor$ in the end. It all depends on the fraction. If you increase $k$ by $1$, will the floor function increase by $0?$ $1?$ $2?$ $3?....$ You can't predict that.

Comment: Are you talking about doing this on a computer or doing it by hand?  Further, if you are doing it on a computer, are you really doing this calculation multiple times with no correlation between variables?

Comment: @DanielV: Computer. There is correlation (e.g., I don't compute the same expression twice) but I'm not done thinking about a specialized algorithm for the correlated case to try to post it for others quite yet. The problem just got me wondering about the general problem from a mathematical standpoint so I posted it here. I should perhaps also mention that requires me to store extra data in between computations is almost certainly going to be a non-starter given that no amount of speed gain here would be worth the extra space it'd consume.

Comment: @DanielV: That said, if you *know* that the uncorrelated case doesn't have a known solution, but do know of a solution for a reasonably general correlated case, feel free to post it and I'll accept it regardless of whether it works for my program.

Comment: @Righter: If you could link to something and/or explain how you know this is unpredictable (unless P = NP or whatever) that could probably be a fine answer too.

Comment: What I mean to say is, this problem is only meaningful if you are computing f(k, m, n) millions of times.  And if you are doing that, it is unusual if (k,m,n) really are different and unrelated in each calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Provided the $\bmod$ operation is faster on whatever platform you'll be running your algorithm (it usually is), then
$$\require{cancel}
\frac{(\cancel{km}+m)-((km+m)\bmod n)-\cancel{km}+(km\bmod n)}{n}
$$
matches your expression with just one integer division. In fact, the numerator must be a multiple of $n$. This is just an application of this formula
$$
\left\lfloor \frac{x}{y} \right\rfloor y = x - (x \bmod y)
$$
which is valid for positive $y$.

Comment: Interesting, it seems you replaced 1 mul + 1 div with 2 mods? It's not obvious to me if it's faster but I could give it a try I guess, thanks. +1 (Actually, now I'm wondering: maybe we can compute the first mod from the second one?)

Comment: Without knowing much about the platform and its capabilities, it's hard to tell if $\bmod$ makes any difference, I agree. But given the parameters of the problem, my suggestion is the only one I could think of. The advantage of $\bmod$ is that we can stay in the realm of integers, and avoid floating-point operations. Even the final division is integral. As for computing a $\bmod$ from the other one, I doubt it, unless you know in advance something about the relationship between $m$ and $n$, and I think you indicated that it's not the case.

Comment: The platform is just x86/x64, though maybe it's best to keep this somewhat abstract. Yeah I definitely don't want to go into floats either. For computing a mod from another one, I think I might be able to assume $m < n$, so we know we don't skip a multiple? But I'll probably accept this answer in any case if it ends up being any faster. Thanks!

Comment: This discussion takes me down on Nostalgia Lane. A long time ago, processors and compilers were quite rubbish, and every FPU operation was costly and required waiting. That's how I came to learn manual (assembler) optimization tricks like the one I presented here. Nowadays, compilers have become quite good at optimizing and interleaving APU and FPU operations so as to minimize delays. Who knows, if the rest of your code is extremely APU intensive, the above construct might end up being actually slower...

Comment: Haha, I think it actually does end up slower, yeah. Here's an example - try switching between `#if 0` and `#if 1` to see which one takes less time: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/6jq79rM3P

Comment: Results are consistent with $\bmod$ being exactly as slow as the division, so yeah, bummer.

Comment: Yeah. I almost wanted to comment saying that I'd heard that's the case, but I'd never actually verified it so I gave it a try. Nice try though!

Comment: If you know $m<n$ then the algorithm you want is just a test to see whether the answer is $0$ or $1.$ The answer that starts with $a=m \bmod n$ does this for the more general case where $m$ and $n$ can be any positive numbers.

Answer (score 0):

My method has the following set up:

1. Calculate $a=m\ mod\ n$
2. Check the sign of  $\left(a(k+1) \ mod\ n -a\right)$
3. If its $\geq 0$, then $\frac{m-a}{n}$ is the answer
4. Otherwise, (if $<0$) its $\frac{m-a}{n}+1$

I hope it suits your needs.

Comment: If this algorithm is satisfactory, I shall post its working out

Comment: Is this too slow?

Comment: If you have to do all this every time then it's slower than the straightforward algorithm: three div or mod operations instead of two. But if you repeat it many times keeping the values of $m$ and $n$ constant but using different values of $k,$ you can keep $a$ and $(m-a)/n$ in memory and each new result costs just one mod operation.

Answer (score 0):

Most processors have a command to compute div and mod at the same time (2 for the price of 1).  Check your manual.  For example: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/div

So you can do

```
(a, b) = div_mod(k*m, n)
b += m
while b >= n {
    b -= n
    a += 1
}
return a
```

If you know the relation between `m` and `n` in advance, then you can do:

```
z = m/n*n
------------
(a, b) = div_mod(k*m, n)
b += (m - z)
a += (b >= n)
return a
```

But notice each line has a write-read dependency with the command before it.  So it might actually be faster to just computer the result with 2 modulus since that can be done in parallel.  You just have to test it.

But the best thing would be to know what you are actually doing, for example if you are looping over k, then the div_mod can probably be skipped altogether.